# Config for webpack expose-loader after upgrade to v1.0

Tags: webpack

The webpack.config.js line for exposing the Bluebird promise library in my (Aurelia) webapp is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]bluebird[\/\\].+\.js$/,
        loader: 'expose-loader?Promise'
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I have since updated the expose-loader to v1.0.
Now, after bundling,  I get this error in the browser console:

> Error: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/expose-loader/dist/cjs.js): ValidationError: Invalid
> options object. Expose Loader has been initialized using an options
> object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - options misses the property 'exposes'. Should be:    non-empty string | object { globalName, moduleLocalName?, override? } |
>   [non-empty string | object { globalName, moduleLocalName?, override?
>   }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)

How should the config be changed to reflect the new API?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem upgrading.

This worked for me:

```
{
  test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]bluebird[\/\\].+\.js$/,
  loader: 'expose-loader',
  options: {
    exposes: {
      globalName: 'Promise',
      override: true
    },
  }
},
```

Based on the following example and a little guess work: https://www.npmjs.com/package/expose-loader

Comment: Many thanks for the advice. I cannot verify that it is the correct solution though, as based on advice from the Aurelia community I had actually removed Bluebird as a dependency from my app before you posted your answer. I can let you know that I have not encountered any issues after doing so, so it seems safe to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I was using AngularJS. From checking the console, Angular was suggesting installing angular-route. For whatever reason, that fixed the issue.